# Does the \import command slow down typesetting compared to \input?

Tags: input, import

Using the `\import` command (instead of the `\input` command) in order to be able to use relative paths is in some situations very convenient for me. However, it seems that, in particular for large documents with many `\import` commands, this seems to slow down the typesetting.

Can anyone confirm this observation or explain this behaviour. Thanks in advance. Manuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` is a very small package which is just a minor, mostly cosmetic, re-arrangement of the file handling. So it will have a theoretical but probably not measurable effect on the timing of  actual `\input` (the time to access the filesystem and load the file will vastly out weigh any differences in the tex macro layer due to the package) and it will have no effect at all on the processing of any tex macros within the file once loaded.